# Laravel 8 yield function

Tags: laravel, templates, laravel-blade

I am just updating stuff to Laravel 8 from 7 and I am trying something simple.

My /layouts/app file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{{ asset('siteimages/favicon.ico') }}">
    <title>Daddies Control</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    @yield('morehead')
   </head>
   <body class="font-sans antialiased">
    <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
        @include('layouts.navigation')

        <!-- Page Heading -->
        <header class="bg-white shadow">
            <div class="mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                @yield('header')
            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <main>
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
    @yield('morescripts')
   </body>
   </html>
```

my test dashboard file is:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('morehead')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/stt.css') }}">
@endsection

@section('header')
dashboard
@endsection

@section('content')
some content
@endsection

@section('morescripts')
 <hr/>
 a script
@endsection
```

The section 'morescripts' is being ignored completely. I use this to add specific datascript (such as datatables).

Comment: May be your blade loaded from compiled cache, clear it with `php artisan view:clear` or `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: I have done that a couple of times.

Comment: the other content `content`,`morehead` loaded successfully? make sure that you end all section with `@endsection`

Comment: everything except the final section works and I have checked that the endsection is there

Answer (score 1):

if you are including written js code at morescripts section then your code should be like

```
<script>
@yeild('morescripts')
</script>
```

and if you want add script links the you should add like below

```
@section('morescripts')
<script src= "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
@endsection
```

for specifically datatables you can use

```
@section('morescripts')
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // your inline script
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

if this didn't work
try by replacing `@endsection` by `@stop`